# Curl return empty in php

Tags: php, curl

```
    $loginUrl = 'http://mp3.zing.vn/json/song/get-source/ZmJmTknNCBmLNzHtZbxtvmLH';
    $agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$loginUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    var_dump(json_decode($result));
```

I have a problem to get the data using curl operation. If i use the url only in my browser then it returns the data but here i using var_dump its null. I have consult some post in stackoverflow but i cant sovle this problem.

Where i do some mistake, please help my. Thanks

Comment: You should var_dump($result); This might not be valid JSON, so json_decode() return null.

Comment: thanks for reply. I try it already, but it return empty

Answer (score 0):

The URL is invalid, i.e. the path mentioned as the variable $loginURL doesnot exist.

```
loginUrl = 'http://mp3.zing.vn/json/song/get-source/ZmJmTknNCBmLNzHtZbxtvmLH';
```

Comment: this URL return string `{"msg":0,"data":[{"id":"ZW8060WC","name":"Cô Gái Của Anh (G-House)","artist":"Cao Thái Sơn","link":"/bai-hat/Co-Gai-Cua-Anh-G-House-Cao-Thai-Son/ZW8060WC.html","cover":"http://zmp3-photo-td.zadn.vn/cover_artist/9/a/9a1c98034bb3c324a7eaea5f3b8b5474_1499078057.jpg","qualities":["128","320"],"source_list":["http://zmp3-mp3-s1-tr.zadn.vn/7538e1c63882d1dc8893/9149364055649420770?key=wDBPKCvXxcA-IKEIyeaYww&expires=1499304120",""],"source_base":"http://","lyric":""}]}`